# "this month" with Ruby date library in a particular format?

Tags: ruby, date, time

So I'm trying to assign a variable `@time` to be the first day of the current month in %d-%b-%Y format. So `@time` today would be "01-Mar-2012".

At first I tried: 
`@time = (Date.today << 1).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")` but this goes 1 month in the past, so it returns `@time` as "06-Feb-2012".

I know I can get the month as a fixnum with `@time = Date.today.mon` but that doesn't help me get to "01-Mar-2012" unless I can convert 3 to Mar and use `Date.year` for the last part of the string.

I tried looking closely through the `Date` library to find a way to convert a number to the equivalent 3 letter month var, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first day will always be 01, so unless I misunderstood the question, this should do it:

```
Date.today.strftime("01-%b-%Y")
```

Comment: Lol wow! I didn't know I could hardcode a 01 into the day. You're too kind.